# How can I change the font of items in alertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have `alertDialog` with items,

this is the code:

```
  final CharSequence[] options = { "Back","continue"};
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity.this);
              builder.setTitle(customTitle);

                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (options[item].equals("Back"))
                        {

                            //do something;


                        }
                        else if (options[item].equals("continue"))
                        {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });
                builder.show();
```

I have custom font in my assets folder, how can I connect the item's font to this font?
I saw many answers but there is no answer for itmes in dialog, all answers was about the title or text uses by textView,
I need to change the font of my items, someone can help me?

Comment: I looked on the same questions but didn't finde answer to my specific question, can someone that did the same help me?

Answer (score -2):

To do this you use alert builder to build your alert. You then get the TextView from this alert and then you set the typeface for the alert.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/yourfont.ttf"); 
textView.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: I tried this way but the app crashed, this way is change the font  to the items also? where in the code I need to add this lines? maybe I didn't put them at the correct line?

Comment: You have to add the code in your `onCreate` method. plus you need to add the font file in your assets. If your api is <20 and you have your font file in your assets the it should work. It changed only the font of the dialog.

Comment: take a look at this post if you cant make it. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601/
Good Luck.

Comment: what this line mean? AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show(); where i need to place my alertDialog?

Comment: the link is talks about textViews, what about alertDialog items? I don't understand your answer...